# How to draw horizontal diagram flow

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw using TikZ the following horizontal diagram without the border and only the figure?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need the 3D/shadowing effect?  It complicates matters without really adding anything.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The purpose of this site is to help you if you have problems with a code, not to convert screen shots to a code. I hope that this code gives you enough motivation to try yourself.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shadows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
  every node/.append style={on chain,fill opacity=0.8,draw,
  join},every join/.style={thick,-latex},
  cs/.style={minimum width=4.5cm,copy shadow={shadow scale=1, shadow xshift=0.5ex, shadow yshift=-0.5ex}}
  ]
 \node[fill=white,cs] (N1) {\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}cp{1cm}}
   Input & $y$ &\\
   & \tiny NX2 & 
  \end{tabular}};
 \node[fill=orange,cs] (N2) {\begin{tabular}{c}
   Conv1D Layer\\
  \tiny NX2 
  \end{tabular}};
 \node[fill=orange,cs] (N3) {\begin{tabular}{c}
   Conv1D Layer\\
  \tiny NX2 
  \end{tabular}};
 \node[circle,minimum size=8mm,thick,font=\Huge\bfseries] (C) {+};
 \node[fill=white,cs] (N4) {\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}cp{1cm}}
   Output & $q_\Phi(x,y)$ &\\
   & \tiny NX2 & 
  \end{tabular}};
\end{scope}  
 \path (N1) -- (N2) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux);
 \draw[thick,-latex] (aux) to[out=0,in=30,looseness=2.7] (C);
 \path (N2) -- (N3) node[pos=0.5,right,font=\bfseries\itshape]{SoftSign};
 \path (C) -- (N4) node[pos=0.5,right,font=\bfseries\itshape]{Sigmoid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]